# Unrooted tests displayed in JUnit runner

Tags: junit, karate

When I run my karate tests, the tests do not show up nested under the applicable feature files in the JUnit results view. They instead show up as Unrooted Tests. I have searched online and tried different suggestions with no luck.

Note that the tests run fine regardless (even from command line). The issue is how they display in the JUnit results, making it difficult to isolate scenarios.

I am in Eclipse Jee Oxygen with JUnit4. I can reproduce this when running the example tests that are generated when creating a new Karate project (see attached screenshot).

Any ideas on how to resolve? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in Eclipse, refer this: https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/issues/1370

Do note that you will get a nice HTML report, which suffices for most needs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#junit-html-report

Comment: I tried my projects with IntelliJ and it displays fine, so it does appear to be an Eclipse issue. Yes, the html report works also. Thanks for the response and a great product.

Comment: @AyoO apologies - this is indeed a bug in karate's junit integration implementation. I'll most likely release a 0.7.0.1 for this, refer this issue: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/329 - by any chance if you can build from source and test that would be great

Comment: This appears fixed. I added a note to the issue.

Comment: confirmed fixed in v0.7.0.1